# How does tokenURI is set in the ERC721 implementation?

Tags: blockchain, erc-721, openzeppelin-contracts

Recently, I was studying the ERC721 smart contract and came across something which I coult not understand.

Look at the following code -

```js
    function tokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view virtual override returns (string memory) {
        _requireMinted(tokenId);

        string memory baseURI = _baseURI();
        return bytes(baseURI).length > 0 ? string(abi.encodePacked(baseURI, tokenId.toString())) : "";
    }
```

It depicts the tokenURI() method implementation in the ERC721 token.

Also, look at the _baseURI implementation written inside ERC721-

```js
    function _baseURI() internal view virtual returns (string memory) {
        return "";
    }
```

Now, in the `tokenURI()` method, the `_baseURI()` returns `""` and hence setting the variable `baseURI` to `""`.
If we do `bytes(baseURI).length` for `baseURI=""`, we get 0 and hence the condition `bytes(baseURI).length > 0` always evaluates to false and in turn `tokenURI(tokenId)` for any `tokenId` always returns `""`

Also, check out this -
[image: trial]

Now my doubt is how the tokenURI which is the concatenation of baseURI and tokenId is set and returned.

Please let me where am I understanding it wrong.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `_baseURI()` function is `virtual` and is supposed to be overridden from a derived contract and actually return a string value that the developer that overrides it considers.

For example:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.16;

import "https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";

contract MyERC721 is ERC721("Abc", "ABC") {

    function doSomething(uint256 tokenId) public view returns(string memory) {
        return tokenURI(tokenId);
    }

    function _baseURI() internal view override returns (string memory) {
        return "myBaseUrl";
    }

    // more logic

}
```

Notice how I inherited from `ERC721` contract.

I overrode the `_baseURI()` function. Then, on the `doSomething` function I call `tokenURI`, which in turn will call `_baseURI()`, but not the `_baseURI()` with the empty string in it, but the `_baseURI()` function that I overrode with the "myBaseUrl" string.

So, the `ERC721` is providing you with a base functionality so you override any `virtual` function that you need to add your desired logic/data.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Understood it well!